What in my code is locking the database file, preventing me to backup?
I have these methods to backup my SQLite database and upload it to my blob container:
public static async Task<string> CreateBackupAsync()
{
    // Generate the timestamped backup file name
    var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    var backupFileName = $"backup_{timestamp}.db";
    var backupFilePath = Path.Combine("C:\\Backups", backupFileName);

    // Ensure the backup directory exists
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Backups");

    using (var location = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={LocalDbPath}"))
    using (var destination = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={backupFilePath}"))
    {
        await location.OpenAsync();
        await destination.OpenAsync();
        location.BackupDatabase(destination);
    }

    return Path.GetFullPath(backupFilePath);
}

public static async Task UploadFileAsync(string filePath)
{
    var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(ConnectionString));
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"database/backup/{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");

    try
    {
        // Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
        await using var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fs, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
    }
}

When in my program:
var backup = await DatabaseSynchronizer.CreateBackupAsync();
await DatabaseSynchronizer.UploadFileAsync(backup);

the code reaches:
await using var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)

I have an exception:

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:...\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\backup_20240702114910.db' because it is being used by another process.'

The file is locked until I shutdown my app. I can't find a solution. I've found that location.BackupDatabase(destination); calls this method:
public virtual void BackupDatabase(SqliteConnection destination)
{
    BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main");
}

Which eventually calls:
public virtual void BackupDatabase(SqliteConnection destination, string destinationName, string sourceName)
{
    if (State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.CallRequiresOpenConnection("BackupDatabase"));
    }

    if (destination == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");
    }

    bool flag = false;
    if (destination.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        destination.Open();
        flag = true;
    }

    try
    {
        using sqlite3_backup sqlite3_backup = raw.sqlite3_backup_init(destination.Handle, destinationName, Handle, sourceName);
        if (sqlite3_backup.IsInvalid)
        {
            SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(raw.sqlite3_errcode(destination.Handle), destination.Handle);
        }

        SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(raw.sqlite3_backup_step(sqlite3_backup, -1), destination.Handle);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            destination.Close();
        }
    }
}

This may be the problem but I am still investigating.

You still need to go deeperuntil you reach the file open+close lines, we do not know if sqlite3_backup_init closes the file handle. Maybe you are not using something like sqlite3_backup_finishorclose.

Please post a complete minimal reproducible example - no lose snippets. Remove all unnecessary code from it (like database handling etc) so that we don't get distracted by irrelevant code. This way we can properly review your code. If I were you, I would create a new empty project to build that example by incrementally adding code until the issue appears. Along that process you may even identify the issue yourself.

@BionicCode the smallest piece of code you could run to help is CreateBackupAsync() which make use of the namespace using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;  if you run that method on a sample sqlite database file you will see that when the method returns the backupFilePath File  is still locked. and that`s where I got lost

Perhaps VACUUM INTO will be easier to use than the Backup API.

In your code, you are calling sqlite3_backup_init() (likely via interop call) which is creating a handle to the file to be written but you are not calling sqlite3_backup_finish() which

is called to release all resources associated with the backup
operation

hence freeing the handle and the file.
reference: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html

A tool to analyze such issue is Microsoft SysInternals Process Explorer. Use the menu Find / Find Handle or DLL and enter the file name. Process Explorer will then list processes which have the file in use.

If it's not your own process, then it's likely a virus scanner.
If you don't like downloading software, you can use Resource Monitor. On the CPU tab, expand Associated Handles and search there.


From the OP description of the behavior, it's not an external program (that would make a duplicate) but the program itself.

it`s not an external program indeed. there must be something locking the file within my methods

Once the culprit process has been identified (see Thomas Weller's answer for that), the OS feature "Handle Tracing" can be used to determine what code inside the process is responsible for leaving a handle open.
See WinDbg commands

!handle (or use Process Explorer to find the numeric value of the handle)

!htrace -diff might make it less necessary to go searching for handle values.


!htrace (to find the function which opened the offending handle)


Before !htrace can be used, handle tracing must be enabled. One way to enable handle tracing is to enter the !htrace -enable command. When handle tracing is enabled, stack trace information is saved each time the process opens a handle, closes a handle, or references an invalid handle. It is this stack trace information that !htrace displays.

Of course since you have .NET code, you'll want the "Son of Strike" managed debugger extensions also running, so that stack traces through managed code can be properly displayed.
This won't answer the question of what you were supposed to do to clean up the handle (instead of leaking it).  But it will point you to the code that opened the handle in the first place.

Isn't there an alternative in VS2022 ? There should be !

Son of Strike, IMHO

@ThomasWeller: That's correct, thanks.
